# MBProgressHud not hiding after second look

Tags: iphone, mbprogresshud

I have a `MBProgressHUD` that I want to display when switching tabs. This is in my app delegate. I have this code here to display the HUD on only the first three tabs

```
 -(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

  if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {  
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex >= 3) {

        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) viewController;
        [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];            
    }

    else {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) viewController;

        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:nav.view];
        [nav.view addSubview:HUD]; 
        HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
        [HUD show:YES];

        [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];            
    }
  }
}
```

The first time I view my page it works but going back to it a second time it doesn't hide. I have my `[appDel.HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1.0];` in my `viewDidAppear`.

How can I get the HUD to hide every time I visit the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be adding the MBProgressHUD to a different view within the UINavigationController. Then you're popping to the root, and it's trying to remove an MBProgressHUD that doesn't exist. Try this (untested code)...

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) viewController;
[nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

if(![nav.visibleViewController.view.subViews containsObject:MBProgressHUD])
{
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:nav.visibleViewController.view animated:YES];
    MBProgressHUD.labelText = @"Loading";  
}
else
{
     [MBProgressHUD setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: this is in the else part of my `didSelectViewController` correct?

Comment: Yes. Within the else brackets. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: Well I figured this is where it goes but it still does not work. The first time works but not the second.

Comment: Sorry, the code I was writing was not tested. I meant to write nav.visibleViewController.view.subviews (subviews is a property of UIView)

Comment: The HUD will never get displayed this way. the line `if(HUD!=nil)` will never go into because the HUD was never created.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the MBProgressHUD view was already activated if so hid it, or simply do so:

```
if (!HUD) {
    [self showLoadingHUD];
}
```